# SparkSQL over REST API not JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

What is the successor to this:
https://github.com/VeritoneAlpha/jaws-spark-sql-rest
?

It does not support Spark 2 version. Would like to pass query into curl request and get a response of the rows retrieved by the query in json format.

Comment: Try Apache Livy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Livy works well with Spark 2.3